# Unable to load format ("command not found")

Tags: texlive, tex-core, format-files

I've created two files: myformat.tex, and mymanuscript.tex. The former's contents are

```
\def\hello{hello}\dump
```

The latter's contents are

```
\hello, world!\bye
```

I've created a .fmt file from the former by running

```
tex myformat
```

I then tried to compile mymanuscript.tex with the format myformat.fmt by running

```
tex &myformat mymanuscript
```

The compilation halted with the following message on the console:

```
3] 1398
-bash: myformat: command not found
> This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=tex)
**
```

Comment: When you run `tex myformat` it runs tex with the default (plain) format already. So you need `initex myformat` or `tex --ini myformat`. With your above `myformat.tex` that gives an error because `{` and `}` haven't been assigned their catcodes. So you should define those, or probably you want `\input plain` at the top of your `myformat.tex` (because you want `\bye` etc to work). And when loading the format file, to make sure `&` isn't eaten by the shell, you can use `tex \&myformat mymanuscript` or `tex '&myformat' mymanuscript` or (at least in web2c TeX) `tex -fmt=myformat mymanuscript`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tex myformat
```

will not make a format, you should have the message

```
(\dump is performed only by INITEX)
```

traditionally you needed

```
 initex myformat
```

but these days it is rolled in to one executable so use

```
tex --ini myformat
```

also in bash you need to use `\&` to hide the `&` from the shell.

In unix shells `&` is the command separator to run a command in the background

```
tex &
```

starts tex as a background job (which will then fail as it requires terminal input)

then the shell will try to run

```
myformat mymanuscript
```

and fail as it can not find a command called `myformat`